# Nagas are believed to be a real tribe what about Garuda?

Tags: garuda

A lot of evidence points to the fact that Nagas and Nagaloka etc. in Mahabharata might be losely connected with modern day Nagas.

Do we know if Garuda also maps to some tribe ?